# Multiple segues remove navigation bar in view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, segue

I have a view controller that has a navigation bar. It is the root view controller of the navigation controller. I have another view controller that can be segued from a button on the first controller. Up to this point, everything works fine; there are navigation bars on both view controllers.

However, from the second view controller, I want to be able to segue back to the first controller. When doing this, it removes the navigation bar from both of the view controllers.

How can I get the navigation bar on both view controllers with buttons as transitions? Thanks!

Comment: did you try setting setNAvigationBArHidden to NO? Are you popping from second to first vc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement below method in your both viewcontroller,

```
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

}
```

You may hiding `navigationbar` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this through the storyboard?

Comment: See, by default navigation bar is not hidden. You have hide it somewhere by mistake. click on your navigation controller on storyboard and make sure that in attributes inspector `shows navigation bar` is checked!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in storyboard:

Select the navigation controller -> Attributes Inspector -> Under Navigation controller and Bar Visibility leave the "Show navigation bar" blank